# How to include a js file in index.html of a webpack project?

Tags: html, webpack, browserify

Right now I'm working on a Vue.js project and need to include a browserified js file into my index.html, but I cannot find a single way to do it!

However I change the src I put in `<script></script>` tag, I always get a 404 not found error.

Btw there is no CDN for that package, so I cannot include it by an cdn.

So I'm wondering if anyone can help me with that.

Comment: are you using vue-cli

Comment: This problem doesn't involve vue

Comment: Showing your project directory structure would be helpful